# How can I Enable VERBOSE log for PowerPivot Service in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, logfile

I use Share Point 2013.

I have some problem in my PowerPivot Service and I need to create (enable) Log.

How can I Enable VERBOSE log for PowerPivot Service in SharePoint 2013 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an article on this:

Configure Event Logging (PowerPivot for SharePoint)
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210681(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210681%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

And I found this Link for

Configure and View SharePoint Log Files and Diagnostic Logging (PowerPivot for SharePoint)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210652.aspx